# Recipients of the weekly reports in Microsoft Family

Tags: microsoft-account

I have quite typical Microsoft Family based on four separate Microsoft accounts:

- two accounts for parents,
- two accounts for children.

Both children has weekly activity e-mail reports enabled.

We're living in Poland and Polish is our native language, but for the sake of Microsoft Family everything is setup in English (the page itself loads in English) as we (parents) have all our browsers installed in English, having English setup as primary language.

Each week I am receiving a report in English with my name in the beginning. My wife isn't getting any kind of reports.

The best part here is that **our children is getting these reports as well**:

- both of them are getting each weekly report in two copies,
- first copy is in English and is titled with my name,
- second copy is in Polish and it title with my wife's name.

What am I missing here? Why children are getting reports about their activity? They shouldn't in my opinion. If they should (according to Microsoft) then why these reports are title with parent's names.

I haven't been defining anything around who, when and in which language should receive reports. I have simply create a Microsoft Family consisting of two adult Microsoft accounts and two Microsoft accounts for children. And I have checked the knob for each children to generate weekly reports.

Is this some kind of bug that we're all receiving these reports in a kind of weird combination? Is there any option to control this feature (i.e. decide who and when gets these reports and -- most important -- to block receiving them by children)?